# How can I solve for Root element is missing issue?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

My plan is checking whole xml in below code, but I got an error.
How can I solve "System.Xml.XmlException: 'Root element is missing.'" this error?

My purpose : checking xml is well formed or malformed line by line.

[image]

**Please check below  (Resource1.Payload is xml)**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<elements>
  <element>A</element>
  <element>B</element>
  <element>C</element>
</elements>
```

```
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using XmlParser3;


string doc = Resource1.Payload;


XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
var errors = new StringBuilder();

var srStringReader = new StringReader(doc);

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.CloseInput = true;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(srStringReader);
XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();
schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);



settings.Schemas.Add(schemaSet);
settings.ValidationFlags =
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings |
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessIdentityConstraints |
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema |
    XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;


 var reader1 = XmlReader.Create(srStringReader,settings);
document.Load(reader1);
document.Validate((o, e) =>
{
    //Do your error logging through e.message 
    errors.AppendLine(e.Exception.Message);
});

Console.WriteLine(errors);
```

Comment: And what is the purpose of this exercise? Are you trying to get data or just exercising?

Comment: I've removed your Visual Studio tag because this isn't a question about using the Visual Studio application. I've also removed the ASP.NET Core tag because this doesn't have any challenges unique to a web application, and furthermore doesn't seem to be a web application at all: it seems to be a console application. Please refrain from adding incorrect tags to your questions.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `Resource1.Payload`?

Comment: hi @JonathanDodds I updated my question and trying to check above  xml is well formed or malformed but line by line? via Resource1.Payload;

Comment: Xml file is good.  Make sure you do not have any characters before the first open angle bracket.

Comment: Your purpose is flawed already. You cannot check xml "line by line". It just doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are reading from the `StringReader` multiple times. You can only read it once. So you need to create a new one for both the schema inference and for the actual parsing.

```cs
using var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(doc));
```

And

```cs
using var reader1 = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(doc), settings);
```

If you are streaming the data in from something like a file or `HttpRequest` then you would need to cache the data somewhere.

Exactly what the point is of inferring the schema to then use it for validation is unclear. If it's valid XML it should always parse in this case.

Comment: hi @Chalieface, my purpose is that check line by lime if my XML is correct format or if I have an issue I want to add errors that`s it.

Comment: @loki by the nature of xml, you _cannot_ do that "line by line".

Comment: @loki The best way to do that is to just loop the `XmlReader.Read` and catch errors.